# Why use document.write to set a Javascript reference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn Bootstrap and I was studying [this example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/#).  I noticed that they include the Jquery library and other scripts at the bottom of the markup just before the end of the body-- this part I understand.  What I don't get is why JQuery is included using two lines of markup, like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

What is the purpose of the second line?

Is it meant to handle the case where the first line fails or is too slow?  Does writing the script element using `document.write` guarantee an immediate load time?  Or what is the purpose?